# Creating dashboard using VisualForce page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to create a custom dashboard in Sales Force using visual force page. I want to get data from customs objects. For this I write a apex controller

```
<apex:page controller="Sample">
    <apex:chart height="400" width="700" data="{!pweb}">
          <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="pweb2" 
            title="users Count" grid="true"/>
          <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="pweb1" 
            title="Week Days">
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="pweb1" yField="pweb2"
          markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
   </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

and creating a chart using visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="Sample">
    <apex:chart height="400" width="700" data="{!pweb}">
          <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="pweb2" 
            title="users Count" grid="true"/>
          <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="pweb1" 
            title="Week Days">
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="pweb1" yField="pweb2"
          markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
   </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

It's not showing any error but after saving this, when I am clicking on preview button, its not showing anything. Could anyone please help me solve it?

Comment: Seems, you forgot add controller code to the question, please update it. Also, can you check if there are any JS errors in the browser console, when you click on the button?